# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'games.wsgi' when deploying Django app to heroku

Tags: django, heroku, heroku-cli

I'm trying to deploy a Django app to heroku. I get an error of `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'games.wsgi'`  where games is my project name.  My Procfile created is
`web: gunicorn games.wsgi` . I have installed gunicorn. My requirements.txt is

```
asgiref==3.3.4
Django==3.2
gunicorn==20.1.0
pytz==2021.1
sqlparse==0.4.1
```

and pipfile also has `[packages] gunicorn = "*"`
my wsgi file has `os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'games.settings')`

my heroku logs show

```
 File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 551, in manage_workers
2021-06-14T10:51:35.947270+00:00 app[web.1]: self.spawn_workers()
2021-06-14T10:51:35.947294+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 623, in spawn_workers
2021-06-14T10:51:35.947812+00:00 app[web.1]: time.sleep(0.1 * random.random())
2021-06-14T10:51:35.947840+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 242, in handle_chld
2021-06-14T10:51:35.948243+00:00 app[web.1]: self.reap_workers()
2021-06-14T10:51:35.948270+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 525, in reap_workers
2021-06-14T10:51:35.948797+00:00 app[web.1]: raise HaltServer(reason, self.WORKER_BOOT_ERROR)
2021-06-14T10:51:35.949024+00:00 app[web.1]: gunicorn.errors.HaltServer: <HaltServer 'Worker failed to boot.' 3>
2021-06-14T10:51:35.949049+00:00 app[web.1]:
2021-06-14T10:51:35.949050+00:00 app[web.1]: During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
2021-06-14T10:51:35.949050+00:00 app[web.1]:
2021-06-14T10:51:35.949077+00:00 app[web.1]: Traceback (most recent call last):
2021-06-14T10:51:35.949147+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/bin/gunicorn", line 8, in <module>
2021-06-14T10:51:35.949409+00:00 app[web.1]: sys.exit(run())
2021-06-14T10:51:35.949438+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 67, in run
2021-06-14T10:51:35.949744+00:00 app[web.1]: WSGIApplication("%(prog)s [OPTIONS] [APP_MODULE]").run()
2021-06-14T10:51:35.949767+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 231, in run
2021-06-14T10:51:35.950117+00:00 app[web.1]: super().run()
2021-06-14T10:51:35.950143+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 72, in run
2021-06-14T10:51:35.950381+00:00 app[web.1]: Arbiter(self).run()
2021-06-14T10:51:35.950404+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 229, in run
2021-06-14T10:51:35.950785+00:00 app[web.1]: self.halt(reason=inst.reason, exit_status=inst.exit_status)
2021-06-14T10:51:35.950813+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 342, in halt
2021-06-14T10:51:35.951272+00:00 app[web.1]: self.stop()
2021-06-14T10:51:35.951300+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 393, in stop
2021-06-14T10:51:35.951781+00:00 app[web.1]: time.sleep(0.1)
2021-06-14T10:51:35.951810+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 242, in handle_chld
2021-06-14T10:51:35.952157+00:00 app[web.1]: self.reap_workers()
2021-06-14T10:51:35.952180+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 525, in reap_workers
2021-06-14T10:51:35.952629+00:00 app[web.1]: raise HaltServer(reason, self.WORKER_BOOT_ERROR)
2021-06-14T10:51:35.952784+00:00 app[web.1]: gunicorn.errors.HaltServer: <HaltServer 'Worker failed to boot.' 3>
2021-06-14T10:51:36.054399+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2021-06-14T10:51:36.153878+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2021-06-14T10:55:27.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build started by user myname.com
2021-06-14T10:55:50.869971+00:00 app[api]: Deploy dbdd2c5e by user myname.com
2021-06-14T10:55:50.869971+00:00 app[api]: Release v17 created by user myname@gmail.com
2021-06-14T10:55:51.193981+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2021-06-14T10:55:56.765467+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `gunicorn games.wsgi`
2021-06-14T10:55:59.711217+00:00 app[web.1]: [2021-06-14 10:55:59 +0000] [4] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 20.1.0
2021-06-14T10:55:59.711739+00:00 app[web.1]: [2021-06-14 10:55:59 +0000] [4] [INFO] Listening at: http://0.0.0.0:14430 (4)
2021-06-14T10:55:59.711817+00:00 app[web.1]: [2021-06-14 10:55:59 +0000] [4] [INFO] Using worker: sync
2021-06-14T10:55:59.715825+00:00 app[web.1]: [2021-06-14 10:55:59 +0000] [8] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 8
2021-06-14T10:55:59.722359+00:00 app[web.1]: [2021-06-14 10:55:59 +0000] [8] [ERROR] Exception in worker process
2021-06-14T10:55:59.722360+00:00 app[web.1]: Traceback (most recent call last):
2021-06-14T10:55:59.722361+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 589, in spawn_worker
2021-06-14T10:55:59.722361+00:00 app[web.1]: worker.init_process()
2021-06-14T10:55:59.722361+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 134, in init_process
2021-06-14T10:55:59.722362+00:00 app[web.1]: self.load_wsgi()
2021-06-14T10:55:59.722362+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 146, in load_wsgi
2021-06-14T10:55:59.722362+00:00 app[web.1]: self.wsgi = self.app.wsgi()
2021-06-14T10:55:59.722363+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 67, in wsgi
2021-06-14T10:55:59.722363+00:00 app[web.1]: self.callable = self.load()
2021-06-14T10:55:59.722363+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 58, in load
2021-06-14T10:55:59.722363+00:00 app[web.1]: return self.load_wsgiapp()
2021-06-14T10:55:59.722363+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 48, in load_wsgiapp
2021-06-14T10:55:59.722364+00:00 app[web.1]: return util.import_app(self.app_uri)
2021-06-14T10:55:59.722364+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gunicorn/util.py", line 359, in import_app
2021-06-14T10:55:59.722364+00:00 app[web.1]: mod = importlib.import_module(module)
2021-06-14T10:55:59.722364+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
2021-06-14T10:55:59.722365+00:00 app[web.1]: return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
2021-06-14T10:55:59.722365+00:00 app[web.1]: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1014, in _gcd_import
2021-06-14T10:55:59.722365+00:00 app[web.1]: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
2021-06-14T10:55:59.722365+00:00 app[web.1]: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 973, in _find_and_load_unlocked
2021-06-14T10:55:59.722366+00:00 app[web.1]: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'games.wsgi'
2021-06-14T10:55:59.722473+00:00 app[web.1]: [2021-06-14 10:55:59 +0000] [8] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 8)
2021-06-14T10:55:59.738771+00:00 app[web.1]: [2021-06-14 10:55:59 +0000] [9] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 9
2021-06-14T10:55:59.746563+00:00 app[web.1]: [2021-06-14 10:55:59 +0000] [9] [ERROR] Exception in worker process
2021-06-14T10:55:59.746564+00:00 app[web.1]: Traceback (most recent call last):
2021-06-14T10:55:59.746565+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 589, in spawn_worker
2021-06-14T10:55:59.746565+00:00 app[web.1]: worker.init_process()
2021-06-14T10:55:59.746565+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 134, in init_process
2021-06-14T10:55:59.746566+00:00 app[web.1]: self.load_wsgi()
2021-06-14T10:55:59.746566+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 146, in load_wsgi
2021-06-14T10:55:59.746566+00:00 app[web.1]: self.wsgi = self.app.wsgi()
2021-06-14T10:55:59.746567+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 67, in wsgi
2021-06-14T10:55:59.746567+00:00 app[web.1]: self.callable = self.load()
2021-06-14T10:55:59.746567+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 58, in load
2021-06-14T10:55:59.746568+00:00 app[web.1]: return self.load_wsgiapp()
2021-06-14T10:55:59.746568+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 48, in load_wsgiapp
2021-06-14T10:55:59.746568+00:00 app[web.1]: return util.import_app(self.app_uri)
2021-06-14T10:55:59.746568+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gunicorn/util.py", line 359, in import_app
2021-06-14T10:55:59.746568+00:00 app[web.1]: mod = importlib.import_module(module)
2021-06-14T10:55:59.746569+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
2021-06-14T10:55:59.746569+00:00 app[web.1]: return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
2021-06-14T10:55:59.746569+00:00 app[web.1]: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1014, in _gcd_import
2021-06-14T10:55:59.746569+00:00 app[web.1]: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
2021-06-14T10:55:59.746570+00:00 app[web.1]: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 973, in _find_and_load_unlocked
2021-06-14T10:55:59.746570+00:00 app[web.1]: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'games.wsgi'
2021-06-14T10:55:59.746797+00:00 app[web.1]: [2021-06-14 10:55:59 +0000] [9] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 9)
2021-06-14T10:55:59.769510+00:00 app[web.1]: [2021-06-14 10:55:59 +0000] [4] [WARNING] Worker with pid 9 was terminated due to signal 15
2021-06-14T10:55:59.868197+00:00 app[web.1]: [2021-06-14 10:55:59 +0000] [4] [INFO] Shutting down: Master
2021-06-14T10:55:59.868318+00:00 app[web.1]: [2021-06-14 10:55:59 +0000] [4] [INFO] Reason: Worker failed to boot.
2021-06-14T10:55:59.935108+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 3
2021-06-14T10:56:00.034150+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2021-06-14T10:56:01.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build succeeded
2021-06-14T10:56:14.181661+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=gameportaladitya.herokuapp.com request_id=3c6f34d2-b6cd-4d58-a6b2-985e495daf0f fwd="122.177.148.42" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2021-06-14T10:56:15.394506+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=gameportaladitya.herokuapp.com request_id=5693205c-1af0-4846-be22-cf96d5306131 fwd="122.177.148.42" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2021-06-14T10:56:34.499111+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=gameportaladitya.herokuapp.com request_id=b3f8aa4e-b89f-4112-8330-fe52851ff034 fwd="122.177.148.42" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2021-06-14T10:56:36.300878+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=gameportaladitya.herokuapp.com request_id=5b31ffe7-48a2-4751-a388-a526447b1179 fwd="122.177.148.42" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
```

My directory structure is

```
D:.
│   .gitignore
│   Pipfile
│   Pipfile.lock
│   Procfile
│   requirements.txt
│   
│   
└───games
    │   db.sqlite3
    │   manage.py
    │   
    ├───games
    │       asgi.py
    │       settings.py
    │       urls.py
    │       wsgi.py
    │       __init__.py
    │       
    ├───my_games
    │   │   admin.py
    │   │   apps.py
    │   │   models.py
    │   │   tests.py
    │   │   views.py
    │   │   __init__.py
    │   │   
    │   └───migrations
    │           0001_initial.py
    │           __init__.py
    │           
    ├───static
```

Can someone help I have been trying to figure out but everything seems to be correct but still I'm getting this error

Comment: Please check if your gunicorn config file contains the correct path to your application.

Answer (score 0):

Probably it's about Python path.
Had the same problem on Centos8.

Simply changed PYTHONPATH to the directory wsgi.py is in.
In case of Linux it would be export PYTHONPATH='D/games/games'.
If you use IDE, you can manage PYTHONPATH from IDE settings.

Then step one level upper to 'D/games' and then try
`gunicorn games.wsgi:application`.

idk how to change pythonath on Windows but seems this article is all about it:
[How to add to the PYTHONPATH in Windows, so it finds my modules/packages?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3701646/how-to-add-to-the-pythonpath-in-windows-so-it-finds-my-modules-packages)

Comment: Hey, you may want to pretty format your code snippets, something like

export `PYTHONPATH` to the directory `wsgi.py` is in.
In case of Linux it would be `export PYTHONPATH=D/games/games`.